# histogram with normalization in each bin (matlab)

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have two arrays

```
A = rand(40,1)
B = rand(40,1)
```

and I am trying to get a histogram for `A` say with 10 bins, i.e.,

```
[count,center] = hist(A,10)
```

My issue is that for each bin of `A`, I need to divide by the sum of elements of `B` that have the same indices as that of `A`, e.g., if entries 1 and entries 5 of `A` went into the first bin of the histogram of `A`, I need to normalize the bin's center by the sum of entries 1 and 5 of array `B`. If there might be an efficient way to determine the mapping between the indices in `A` and the corresponding bin the histogram, then, might help with this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example with more detail explaining what you want, i.e. A = [2 3 4 5 6 5 2 1 5 ]; B = [ ...]. As it stands, I do not understand what your goal is.

Comment: I am basically trying to find the indices of A that go into each bin of the histogram. Then, I can use this mapping to pull the entries of B that correspond to the appropriate bin in the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

To find which bin data fall into, I recommend migrating to the `histogram` function as it will give you the actual boundaries. My below MATLAB code will add a second row to A with which bin the value the first row belongs to

```
A = randi(20,[1 15])

X = histogram(A,10)

% trim most right hand edge
leftEdge = X.BinEdges(1:end-1)

% initialize bin index
A(2,:) = 0


for k1 = 1:length(leftEdge)
    A(2,:) = A(2,:) + (A(1,:) >= leftEdge(k1));
end

disp(A)
```